# Out of date Skype in software center

Tags: apt, package-management, skype

I've enabled the Canonical Partners sources, but my software centre (or `apt-cache show skype`) both only show skype 4.2.x, rather than the current 4.3.x

Sources such as this [Ubuntu Handbook Article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/skype-4-3-install-in-ubuntu-1404/) imply that 4.3 should be available through software centre.

I've run apt-get update and upgrade, so I think I'm all up to date.

I know I can install manually from the downloaded .deb from Skype's website, but why is my software centre out of date, and how can I get the latest to show up?

I'm running 14.04 LTS.

**EDIT (from comments):**

running: `apt-cache policy skype` yielded:

```
skype:
 Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
 Version table:
    4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy/partner amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and then run `apt-cache policy skype` and post the output to your question.

Comment: You added a repository for Ubuntu 13.10 `saucy` for some reason. If you replace `saucy` with `trusty`, you will get the correct version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added the partner repository for Ubuntu 13.10. That was wrong.
It can be fixed this way:

Run in terminal

```
sudo sed -i 's/saucy/trusty/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

This will install the correct version.

Or you can got to System Settings -> Software & Updates and fix it there.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I now just have to worry about why/when I configured the wrong source :)

Comment: You probably ran some outdated command.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove the old Skype version

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

2. Remove the old Skype folder

```
rm -rf ~/.Skype
```

3. Enable MultiArch if you are running 64-bit Ubuntu

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

4. Since you have already enabled Canonical Partners, run the update.

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't helped, software centre and apt-cache both still show 4.2x (the older version). Thanks.